# Can't see p1 in string replace() callback function, trying to replace hashtags

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to display hashtags in some text. Inside the `replace()` callback `myArray` can't see p1 or p2 as expected.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6c0qw69a/7/

```
var myTempContent = "this text not showing #hash1 nor here #has2 here either. Only #theseHashTags #show nothing here";
var hashTagRegEx = /(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig;

var myArray = [];
var index = 0;

var myTweetContent = myTempContent.replace(hashTagRegEx, function(match, p1, p2) {

    // Output shows value of p2, but NOT p1 ???
    myArray[index] = p1 + "<a href='#'>" + p2 + "</a>";
    index++;

    return (     
        p1 + "<a href='#'>" + p2 + "</a>"
    );
});

// Output doesn't show correct p2, hash # should be inside <a> tag.
console.log("myTweetContent = " + myTweetContent);

// Why is p1 not showing? Also same issue above with p2.
console.log("myArray = " + myArray);
```

Comment: p1 will never be anything but empty or a single space `(^|\s)` matches beginning of line (which results in p1 = empty) or a single space - also, `<link>text</link>`, at least in firefox, renders as `<link></link>text` - really, <link> tagas ae only valid in the <head> ... though, <Link> may be a different story when using reactjs - not familiar enough

Comment: So why does p1 work inside the return here ` p1 + "<Link to='search'>" + p2 + "</Link>"`. But not here ` <span key={index} >
          {p1}<a href="#">{p2}</a>
        </span>` Yes, this is a React-Router tag `<Link>`, links to a different route in your app with optional params.

Comment: what is p1 where you can see it?

Comment: @GiantElk: The space and start-of-string are captured alright. See [proof](http://jsfiddle.net/6c0qw69a/).

Comment: @stribizhev see this updated JSfiddle, not working with this text, `"this text not showing #hash1 nore here #has2 here either. Only #theseHashTags #show nothing here"`, http://jsfiddle.net/6c0qw69a/1/

Comment: I am afraid there is some misunderstanding. p1is shown in the alert as " ". What do you call by p1?

Comment: As per the RegEx p1 should be the part of the string that does not have a `#`, i.e. `(^|\s)`. So the above text p1 will be "This text not showing ", then on next iteration "nore here ".